# Critical section in query SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: locking

I have a stored procedure and I want to run it once at the same time.

In the other hand Like lock variable in C# programing.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this situation you can use 2 solution for your critical section and the block you want to only one time a time

First use **SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE**

For example

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
begin Tran
your Query
Commit Tran
```

Second Use **DeadLock priority normal**

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
    begin Tran
    your Query
    Commit Tran
```